# HTML not rendering in Laravel Views

Tags: php, laravel-4

I'm new to Laravel and I'm trying to understand the correct way to handle web pages using Laravel.

Currently, I have a default route that leads to a file named login.php. login.php contains nothing but html, but when I go to localhost/myapp/public/index.php/ , login.php's html structure is displayed instead of the file rendering.

For example, if I were to say <\p>Hello World<\p> ( without the '\', so a real paragraph tag ) , I would get <\p>Hello World<\p> instead of:

Hello World

My current route is this:

Route::get('/', function(){

```
    return View::make('login');

});
```

And login.php is just a basic html file. When the View gets returned, I get the html without the rendering.

This is my .htaccess file:

Options -MultiViews

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Any ideas? Oh, and sorry about the formatting for this question. I'm new to StackOverflow. Thanks!

Comment: have you started the server? `php artisan server`

Comment: Do you mean php artisan serve ?

Honestly I didn't know I needed to do that. But I did and now I'm getting errors talking saying "Permission Denied,  failed to open stream in bootstrap/compiled.php:4211"

Comment: Can you add the contents of your template? Also, the rendered source, right click -> view page source in Chrome for example.

Comment: just change the route to point to `login` as my answer below not `/`, please test it, and post the results ..

Comment: When I make the update you suggested and type in http://localhost:8000/login.php, I get this error in my errorLog

production.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException' in /home/myName/webSource/myApp/bootstrap/compiled.php:5738

login.php is in the app/views folder as well

Comment: You don't add the .php on the end, just `localhost:8000/login`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that I had to start the Laravel Server in order to actually view my pages.

Once I did

```
php artisan serve
```

and went out to the root of my localhost, everything worked properly.

Comment: What about when you post your project online? You cannot do php artisan serve.

Answer (score 0):

the route file should look like this

```
Route::get('login', function() {
    return View::make('login');
});
```

assuming that `login.php` is in `app/views/` folder.

and this is the url to access the login page assuming you are using artisan to run the server `localhost:8000/login.php`

Comment: now this is totally wrong. in laravel 4, views are located under app/views and you can call your view from whatever route you want, for sure a view is not located in the public folder...